# Merge [phpbb] and [phpbb3] tags as [phpbb]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

I think the following tags should be considered at least as synonyms and could certainly be merged:

[phpbb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpbb) [phpbb3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpbb3) as [phpbb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpbb)

There are:

- 418 questions tagged with [phpbb3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpbb3)
- 526 questions tagged with [phpbb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpbb)
- 149 questions tagged with [phpbb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpbb) and [phpbb3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpbb3)

I don't think it is necessary to split these questions into two tags. I have searched old questions about [phpbb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpbb). There are only 23 questions about *phpBB2* and 5 of them are about converting *phpBB2* to [phpbb3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpbb3).

Most questions are about [phpbb3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpbb3). This isn't surprising, because *phpBB3* is in production since 12 Dec 2007 and the next major version will be 3.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is common to have different tags for different (major) releases of frameworks or software packages (like the PHP bulletin board) on Stack Overflow.

For example, for Zend-Framework releases: [Zend-Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/zend-framework/info) and [Zend-Framework2](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/zend-framework2/info) and [Zend-Framework3](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/zend-framework3/info).

Or for Symfony: [Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/symfony/info), [Symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/symfony2/info) and [Symfony 3](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/symfony3/info)

There are major differences between those packages and they can definitely not be considered synonyms.
I am not familiar with phpBB, but I assume that the fact that those phpBB releases got different version numbers suggest that the developers thought that the differences between them are considerable. This would also justify a different tag on Stack Overflow.

The fact that those different tags are not used as much does not justify treating them as synonyms and merging them into one.

For Symfony there are even different tags for subversions:

[Symfony 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/symfony-2.1/info) up to [Symfony 2.8](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/symfony-2.8/info)
[Symfony 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/symfony-3.1/info)

and more...

Having different tags for subversions of Symfony has been food for discussion before for example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138683/tag-chaos-symfony-and-version-numbers) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137230/retag-symfony-2-0-to-symfony2).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I thought that the fact that those different tags are not used as much **justify** treating them as synonyms. I understand better. For imformation, there are three major releases in phpBB. The phpBB version 2 is no more used currently. We can see some forum in version 3.0 which is the old-stable. The phpBB 3.1, the current stable version, is very different because phpBB3.1 was rebuild from scratch and is now powered by symfony framework.